# How do I get my discord bot to detect certain words from a file? (and also make it able to add, edit and delete words from the file)

Tags: python, discord.py

I am creating a discord bot to detect messages in a channel and notify a user when a keyword is mentioned. I am unable to get the bot to add or remove words from a file. The file is just a list of words/keywords.

I have tried writing to .txt, .json and .csv files to no avail.

```
import discord
import json
import asyncio
import fileinput
from discord.ext import commands

debug = True # Runs debug commands when 'true'
TOKEN = '' # User token for the bot

detector = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$", description='k') # Sets command prefix for bot

with open("wordlist.txt", "r+") as f:
    wordlist = f.read()

@detector.event
async def on_ready(): 
    print("--------")
    print("Bot is online")
    print(detector.user.name)
    print(detector.user.id)
    print("--------")
    game = discord.Game("with VSCode")
    await detector.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=game) # Sets the "Playing: " on discord


@detector.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.author == detector.user: # Don't change unless you're retarded
        return

    for i in wordlist: # Checks messages for matches in the wordlist.txt file
        if not (message.content.find(i) == -1):
            if debug: 
                await message.channel.send("Word found.")

    await detector.process_commands(message) # Processes all commands - DO NOT TOUCH

@detector.command()
async def add(ctx, wd): # Use $add (word) to add words to the wordlist
    if wd in wordlist:
        await ctx.send("You have already added that word.") # Checks if the word is already in the wordlist
    else:
        with open("wordlist.txt", "a") as f:
            f.seek(0, 0)
            f.write(wd + ",")
        if debug: await ctx.send("Word added.") 
    return

@detector.command()
async def remove(ctx, wd): # Use the $remove to remove a word from the wordlist
    with open("wordlist.txt") as f:
        f.seek(0, 0)
        f.read()
        remw = f.read().replace(wd + ",", '')
    if wd not in wordlist: # Detects if the word is in the wordlist
        await ctx.send("That word hasn't been added.")
    else:
        with open("wordlist.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write(remw)

detector.run(TOKEN)
```

The output should be that the bot adds the word to the list / removes it.

When I type $add word, it will add "word" to the list.

When I type $remove word, it should check if the word is already in the file, and remove it.

Comment: There is no variable named "wordlist" initialised anywhere in this chunk of code. Also, double `.read()` in remove, remw will be empty because second `.read()` reads nothing.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I forgot to add in the rest of the code. I have added it in now.

Comment: The main problem is still the double `.read` in remove. Also, could you tell us what is current behaviour? You only provided the code, not how it works now. There are several design flaws I see (separate wordlist and opening/saving the file, seemingly without updating the wordlist variable?) but I need to know how it works before I break something further.

Comment: The way it works is that it opens another file and when the command $add or $remove is used, it adds or removes the word from that list. The on_message function then checks for words matching the ones in the wordlist.

Comment: "open another file" - nope, it's always `wordlist.txt`. "then checks" - nope, it looks like bot executes it on every message, neither add nor remove execute it. You seem to have an idea how your code should work but it's not what you wrote, yet you still claims that it does work as intended. I was asking for *current* behaviour, aka what's wrong at this moment.